# How do I link to a hidden div on another page with Fancybox3

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I am trying to show a hidden div from another web page in a different page so I do not have to change data twice using fancybox 3.   *Since the platform that these pages are a in web content management system there is no way to have a simple database.*

Data is hidden on page like this

```
<div id="yummyfoodhours" style="display: none;">
Mon..Fris..ect</div>
```

link on the page is

```
<a class="btn btn-success fancybox" href="#yummyfoodhours">Hours</a>
```

when it is click a fancybox pops up with the hours

I want to show the page different page and I click the link

```
 <a class="btn btn-success fancybox" href="eat/#yummyfoodhours">Yummy Food Hours Cafe</a>
```

it just show the main page. :-/

Do I need some java to show the hidden div when it is click on?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have to load 2nd page using ajax. Try creating links with selector, like this:

```
href="eat/ #yummyfoodhours" data-type="ajax"
```